# How to Use NOT IN Query in PowerBI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have imported **Order** table from SQL into PowerBI

Order Table has Data Like below.

```
ID   OrderNo   CustomerNo    OrderDate
1      DC001      1001       2020-06-01
1      DC002      1002       2020-06-09
1      DC003      1003       2020-06-10
```

**Note:** I want to Execute below Query in PowerBI DAX

```
Select Count(Distinct CustomerNo) 
From [order] where orderdate >= '2020-06-08' and orderdate <= '2020-06-14' 
And CustomerNo 
Not in (select CustomerNo from [order] where orderdate < '2020-06-08')
```

I have tried below code in DAX

```
MEASURE NOT IN = 
VAR indexList =SELECTCOLUMNS (
    FILTER('Order','Order'[OrderDate] > [RangeFromDate]),"Distict", DISTINCTCOUNT ('Order'[CustomerNo]))
RETURN
    SUMMARIZE (
    FILTER('Order',
        NOT ('Order'[CustomerNo]) IN indexList),
        "Count",Count ( 'Order'[CustomerNo] )
    )
```

Note: *[RangeFromDate]* is MEASURE dynamically load From date from the slicer.

But Not Working for me.
Kindly Help me to solve this in PowerBI DAX

Answer (score 2):

The EXCEPT function can help with this. It will accept two tables as input, taking the values from the first table, and removing those from the second. I've used a summarize function to ensure each of those tables are distinct (the second table also includes the filter from your SQL subquery). Since they are distinct, I can just COUNTROWS of the resulting table to get the customer count.

```
RemainingCustomers = 
COUNTROWS(
    EXCEPT(
        SUMMARIZE(Orders, [CustomerNo]), 
        SUMMARIZE(FILTER(Orders, Orders[OrderDate] < DATEVALUE("2020-06-08")) , [CustomerNo])
    )
)
```